# Comments don't show up in my Chatter Feed

Tags: chatter

My comments to other people's posts on Chatter do not show up in my Feed. If I post something, it does show up in my Feed -- but if I comment on someone else's post, it doesn't. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you get an error ? Does this happen with a specific user or all the users on your org?

Because it could be an option the user choose to activate like the **UserPreferencesDisProfPostCommentEmail** which disable or enable the possiblity to add Comments on a post on a user's profile.